# Why is $\operatorname{span}\{e_{i>k}\}\subset\operatorname{span}\{e_{i\neq k}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am dealing with a rank 1 matrix of the form $u^{(k)}e_{k}^{T}$, where $u^{(k)}$ is only non-zero starting the $k+1^{th}$ entry of the vector. Moreover, $e_{k}^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}0&...&0&1&0&...&0\end{bmatrix}$, therefore the outer product essentially produces a matrix where the first $k$ rows are zero, below these $k$ rows we have the first $k-1$ and the $k+1\to n$ columns are all zero. So, all in all the matrix contains only one non-zero column, with entries starting from $k+1^{th}$ row till $n^{th}$ row and located at the $k^{th}$ column. Hence, this matrix is represented by only this column which implies its name (rank 1 matrix)

To make things easier consider the vector $u^{(4)}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}^{T}$ and $e_{4}^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

The question is this :

> Why is the column space of $\mathcal{C}(u^{(k)}e_{k}^{T})$ a subset of $\mathcal{N}(u^{(k)}e_{k}^{T})$? Here $\mathcal{C}()$ is the column space and $\mathcal{N}()$ is the null space.

Observation : The column space is a **subset** of $\operatorname{span}\{e_{i>4}\}$ and the null space is **equal** to $\operatorname{span}\{e_{i\neq 4}\}$ (at least that's what I observed on MATLAB for the example provided above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $A_k = u^{(k)}e_k^T$. In this case we can compute the null space $N(A_k)$ and the range $R(A_k)$ directly. Note $A_kx = (x, e_k)u^{(k)} = x_ku^{(k)}$. Thus if $u^{(k)} \neq 0$, $N(A_k) = \{x : x_k = 0\}$, $R(A_k) = \text{span}(u^{(k)})$. If $u^{(k)}_k = 0$ then we get $R(A_k) \subseteq N(A_k)$.